# How to convert String input into int and push into a Stack

Tags: java, string, parsing, stack

for example, i have the **string "12,456,544,233"** from the **user input**,

I want to take each number that is separated by commas and push each one into
a Stack, converting it to an **int** in the process because the Stack is .
(array implementation of a stack by the way)

So 12 would be at 0, 456 at 1, 544 at 2, etc...

I KNOW I have to use the Integer class to parse, but just not sure how to setup the loop to do everything, if i didn't provide enough info, ask and I will do so!
thanks.

The code I tried:

```
String input = scan.nextLine();

    stack.push(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.charAt(2))));
```

Comment: Homework? here's a hint: loop over the output of String.split()

Comment: Post the code you tried, or else you'll get a swarm of negative Chi all over you, and the Chi counter in the left upper corner will go all negative...

Comment: sorry i updated it, forgot to include it!

Comment: So you're taking the character `,`, converting it into a String `","`, and passing that to parseInt.

Comment: Hint:  Read the JDK [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).  Everything you need to know is there, if you look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can split strings

```
String string = "12,456,544,233";
String[] individualStrings = string.split(",");
```

`split()` method Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

Next, you can interate over string array and convert each element into integer.

```
for(int i = 0; i < individualStrings.length; i++)
{
  int m = Integer.parseInt(individualStrings[i]);
}
```

Cheers !!

Comment: thank you, what exactly does the string.split do? this code seems close to what i want

Comment: split method splits a given string by matching around regular expression, edited reply as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like homework. so just giving some hints

1. you can use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to split the string into tokens separated by commas
2. now traverse the array that you get after split and push to stack.

N.B. if it is really a homework then may be you need to implement your own split